# Issues while playing a video stream with googletv-video-player example on Google TV

Tags: android, google-tv, android-video-player

I downloaded the **[googletv-video-player example](http://code.google.com/p/googletv-video-player/)** and picked only the **VideoPlayerActivity** as i was only interested in how to play streams.

I modified its xml & java files to play the video in full Screen mode.

here is what i have now:

**player.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:padding="10dp">

<VideoView android:id="@+id/videoViewFullScreen"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**player.java**

```
public class player extends Activity implements
    AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener,
    MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener, MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener {
public static final String TAG = "VPActivity";

public VideoView mVideoView = null; 

// Handle AudioFocus issues
public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
    switch (focusChange) {
    case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN:
        Log.i(TAG, "AF Gain");
        if (mVideoView != null)
            mVideoView.resume();
        break;

    case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS:
        Log.i(TAG, "AF Loss");
        if (mVideoView != null)
            mVideoView.stopPlayback();
        mVideoView = null;
        this.finish(); // Let's move on.
        break;

    case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT:
    case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK:
        Log.i(TAG, "AF Transient");
        if (mVideoView != null)
            mVideoView.pause();
        break;
    }
}

public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    Log.i(TAG, "done.");
    mVideoView = null;
    this.finish();
}

public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
    Log.e(TAG, "IO Error e=" + what + " x=" + extra);
    return false; // Will call onCompletion
}

@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Request Audio Focus
    AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    int result = am.requestAudioFocus(this, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
            AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);
    if (result != AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Can't get AudioFocus " + result);
        this.finish(); // Just give up.
    }

    //added the following to make video large, hide title and keep activity alive
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);  
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    //----------------------------------------------------------------      

    setContentView(R.layout.player);


    mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoViewFullScreen);
    mVideoView.setVideoPath("rtsp://stream-url");
    mVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    mVideoView.setOnErrorListener(this);

    MediaController mc = new MediaController(this, true);
    mc.setMediaPlayer(mVideoView);
    mc.setAnchorView(mVideoView);
    mVideoView.setMediaController(mc);
    mVideoView.requestFocus();
    mVideoView.start();
}
}
```

Now I am having TWO issues

```
 One on Motorola Xoom Tablet and
 Second on Google TV
```

**Issue on Tablet (Android version: 4.0.3)**
This is a small issue. Tablet begins streaming video properly. It plays the video for 15-20 minutes perfectly. but after some time, the video stops playing. I checked its state by tapping on the screen and i realized that the player was automatically **Stopped**.!

[image]

When i tapped on **Play** again.. it began playing stream perfectly.
Why does it stop automatically???

**Issue on Google TV (Android version: 3.1)**

This is a more serious issue. First the google tv was not playing it at all and would give me the following error:

```
Cannot Play Video
-----------------------------------------
Sorry, this video cannot be played.
```

**Edit:** Now this issue has disappeared and video is played....i did nothing.
But y was it behaving in such way??

Now the issue is that Google TV screen only shows the 1/4th part of the video at upper left corner and the remaining video is hidden.... as if the **VideoView** object is stretched while some other object is on top of it with an open window on upper left corner and it hiding the **VideoView**

AND the player activity finishes automatically.

The video even plays in emulator & tablet so i cannot paste the error generated by the emulator (as there is no error there) from LogCat.

**My Android application is built with Android 3.1 library**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your code on GoogleTV and it works fine. The only thing I suggest you need to change for streaming url is this line:

```
 mVideoView.setVideoPath("rtsp://stream-url");
```

The above is for playing local files, for streaming urls use the following instead:

```
 mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("rtsp://stream-url"));
```

Comment: you were right Megha ... it's the stream that was causing issues... thanks